# How to print coordinates above certain points

Tags: plotting

How do I place the x and y values of the points I have found (maxandmindistance) above the point in a plot?

Here is my code so far:

```
Distance[t_] := t*(t - 1)*(t - 1.5)^2*(t - 3)
Velocity[t_] := Simplify[Distance'[t]]
maxandmindistance = Solve[Velocity[t] == 0, t]
Show[Plot[Distance[t], {t, 0, 3}], 
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], 
   Point[{t, Distance[t]} /. maxandmindistance]}]]
```

This results in a function with dots along it. They are the maximum and minimum values for the function. The problem is that the coordinates (x,y values) are not shown.

Comment: Can you explain clearly what you *expect* and what *happens* instead?

Comment: Apologies. I end up with a line function with dots along it. They are the maximum and minimum values for the function. The problem is that the coordinates (x,y values) are not shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
Distance[t_] := t*(t - 1)*(t - 1.5)^2*(t - 3)
Velocity[t_] := Simplify[Distance'[t]]
maxandmindistance = Solve[Velocity[t] == 0, t];
coords = # + Chop[#2 - #] &[Round@#, #] &@({t, Distance[t]} /. 
maxandmindistance);
Show[Plot[Distance[t], {t, 0, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 3.5}, {-2.5, 1.5}}], 
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], 
   Point[{t, Distance[t]} /. maxandmindistance],
   Table[{Black, Text[ToString[coords[[i]]], coords[[i]] + .3]}, {i, 
     Length[coords]}]
   }]]
```

[image]

If needed, you can also double-click on the image and adjust the formatting and the position of each text label to obtain the output you like most.

[image]

Comment: When I entered that in and stretched the graph so that the text did not overlap, the co ordinates just left. They were not attached to the point.

Comment: @GeneralStubbs What do you mean with "stretched the graph"?

Comment: I took one of the corners of the plot and extended it making it larger.

Comment: @GeneralStubbs It doesn't happen to me. The text is defined to be at the same coordinates as the red points plus a shift of .3 to the right and upwards, so it always moves in sync with the red points when stretching the image.

Comment: @GeneralStubbs See the update on how to manually adjust the position of the text labels.

Comment: Very sorry. It's just the text size does not increase. Thank you so much for the answer. An extra thank you for telliong me about the movement.

Comment: @VLC When you answer a question, I would expect that you find the question appropriate for this site. Why don't you upvote the question then? New users need to gain some reputation as well ;-) (btw +1)

Comment: @halirutan You're right, nothing else to say.

Comment: @VLC though double clicking + doing stuff is the easiest way to format the label, is there any way of doing it in the code? For instance, if I wanted to remove the curly brackets, how could I do it? I can imagine that all of the other styling would just imply a `Style` wrapping inside the `Table` (e.g. `Style[Text[ToString[coords[[i]]], coords[[i]] + .3], Bold]`)

Comment: @Sosi To remove the curly brackets replace this: `Text[ToString[coords[[i]]]` with `Text[ToString[coords[[i, 1]]] <> " " <> ToString[coords[[i, 2]]]`. In this way, only the numbers are converted to strings and an extra place is added between them. The `<>` stands for `StringJoin`.

Comment: @vlc thank you!